# how to insert current date in html script

Tags: javascript, html

I have the current script.  var date 2 needs to automatically grab the current date and then do the calculation.  I have tried many things with no luck, please help.

```html
<script>

// Here are the two dates to compare
var date1 = '2015-09-08';
var date2 = '2015-12-13';

// First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
date1 = date1.split('-');
date2 = date2.split('-');

// Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

// We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

// This is the calculated difference in seconds
var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

// in Hours
var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

// in weeks :)
var timeDifferenceInWeeks = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24/7;

document.write(Math.ceil(timeDifferenceInWeeks));
</script>
```

Comment: Do not define `var date2 = '2015-12-13';` hence split operation will not be there..Just `var date2 = new Date();` Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/09aoz9u1/

Comment: if i use your idea the calculation does not happen.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to a php code and the following is what I got to work.

```html
<?
$strtDate = '2015-09-08';
$endDate = date('Y-m-d');

//$endDate = 'new Date();';
$startDateWeekCnt = round(floor( date('d',strtotime($strtDate)) / 7)) ;

// echo $startDateWeekCnt ."\n";
$endDateWeekCnt = round(ceil( date('d',strtotime($endDate)) / 7)) ;

//echo $endDateWeekCnt. "\n";
$datediff = strtotime(date('Y-m',strtotime($endDate))."-01") - strtotime(date('Y-m',strtotime($strtDate))."-01");
$totalnoOfWeek = round(floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) / 7) + $endDateWeekCnt - $startDateWeekCnt ;
echo $totalnoOfWeek ."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date()` to get current date. please refer snippet.

```html
<script>

// Here are the two dates to compare
var date1 = '2015-09-08';
var date2 = '2015-12-13';

// First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
date1 = date1.split('-');
date2 = date2.split('-');

// Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1]-1, date1[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1]-1, date2[2]);

// We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime());
date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime());
date3_unixtime = parseInt((new Date()).getTime());

// This is the calculated difference in seconds
var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;
   
var timeDifferenceInWeeks1 = timeDifference / (1000*60*60*24*7);
var timeDifferenceInWeeks2 = (date3_unixtime - date2_unixtime) / (1000*60*60*24*7);

document.write(Math.ceil(timeDifferenceInWeeks1)+'--'+Math.ceil(timeDifferenceInWeeks2));
</script>
```

Comment: var date2 = new Date(); does not work, if you run the first code above you will get an answer of 14.  if I put var date2 = new Date(); in place of the Var date2 = '2015-12-13'; no answer is resolved.  When i run your code I do not get the correct answer either.  your code gives 14--1 the answer is to be 14 or 15 depending on the current date.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
var date2 = new Date();
```

now the date2 holds the current date and time from your machine.